# UIBezierPath makes corners bold

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

I'm using following code inside UIView `drawRect` to draw rectangle with round corners:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:5];

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, _fillColor.CGColor);
[path fill];

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, _strikeColor.CGColor);
[path stroke];
```

For some reason I'm getting artefact in stroke: bold corners.

[image]

Looks not good. I also tried to have independent path for stroke - same problem.

Comment: screenshot, maybe...?

Comment: @holex sorry, attached one

Comment: try with rect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, 0.5, 0.5)

Comment: Think you have half stroke on edges, not bold on corners.

Comment: This isnt much efficient way to handle things in objective c. It's better to use view's layer's properties like cornerradius, borderWidth, borderColor . Instead filling your rect with color, use backgroundColor property of your view.

Comment: @Krzysztof you are right, that was mistake. Please provide you comment as answer so I could select it.

Comment: that is the simple geometrical issue here... the problem is the _same_ radius you are using for _fill_ and _stroke_. for your example the fill radius should be `4` as long as the line width is `1` and the stroke radius is `5`.

Comment: @deathhorse I use this in table view cell so I avoid using of corner radius for layer because of performance problems.

Comment: @JohnTracid added  answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think that the corners are right, but stroke goes out of view. Try:

```
rect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, 0.5, 0.5)
```

Before creating path.

Answer (score 0):

```
//// Rectangle Drawing
UIBezierPath* rectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(57, 48, 136, 31) byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(5, 5)];
[rectanglePath closePath];
[UIColor.grayColor setFill];
[rectanglePath fill];
```